# Using return value in system.assertequals

Tags: apex, unit-test, invocable-method

I created an Invocable method for Process Builder and am building the test class. I am trying my hand at the system.assertequals statements but I can't figure out how to get the return value from the class I am calling in my test class. Can anyone help me out?

Invocable Class

```
    global class getUnnasociatedCallCount {

   @InvocableMethod
   public static list<string> getRecordCount(List<Id> UserIds) {      
       Integer callcount = [Select Count()
                FROM Task
                WHERE Status = 'In Progress'
                AND WHATID = NULL
                AND RecordType.Name = 'Five9 Call'
                AND OwnerID IN :UserIds
                AND CreatedDate >= 2018-06-01T00:00:00Z
                AND CreatedDate = LAST_90_DAYS];

    list<string> calllist = new list<string>();
    CallList.add(string.valueof(callcount));
    return callList;
   }
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class test_getUnnasociatedCallCount {
@testSetup static void setupTestData(){

        ***Code Removed***
    }

    //Create Task linked to Session 
    @isTest static void testLinkedToSession(){

        User    uBCS    = [Select Id,Name 
                           FROM User 
                           WHERE Alias = 'TSTBCS'];

        List<Id> bcslist = New List<Id>();
        bcsList.add(uBCS.Id);

        System.runAs(uBCS){

            test.startTest();

            List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

            Task t      = new Task();
            t.Subject   = 'Test Call - Not Associated';
            t.Type      = 'Five9 Call';
            t.Status    = 'In Progress';
            taskList.add(t);

            insert taskList;

            //Calling the invocable method
            getUnnasociatedCallCount.getRecordCount(bcslist);

            //Check that the return value equals 1 as we only created one task above. 
            //system.assertEquals(1, ????);

            test.stopTest();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach here should be the same as with any other static method returning a value.

You need to *cache* the result.

```
List<String> result = MyClass.myMethod();
```

If you want to assert on its size, you can do so:

```
system.assertEquals(1, result.size(), 'Do not neglect meaningful messages!');
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that invocable methods are just like any other static method. They just happen to have the annotation to show up on the process builder and flow interfaces.

Comment: Fair enough. Added.